# SciPy genextreme.fit gives: "RuntimeWarning: divide by zero"

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I'm trying to do a GEV-fit using the genextreme package in SciPy. Although I can get it to estimate the parameters, I get a warning that it is dividing by zero.

I tried to fit different data sets, tried to set different initial values for the shape parameter c, and also tried to multiply the data by e.g. 100. None of it worked. I'm using Python 2.7.12 and SciPy 0.17.0.

I'm new to Python and wanted to do a quick first test with my existing installation.

The data given in the code is roughly Gumbel distributed (c=0), since I have checked it on a Gumbel plot and made a Gumbel fit using linear regression.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import genextreme as gev
t=np.array([3.8482, 3.6435, 3.0417, 4.0329, 3.2967, 3.3535, 3.6179, 3.3042, 3.6164, 3.5855, 2.7932, 2.8833, 2.6513, 2.7794, 3.2649, 3.2613, 3.1736, 3.1131, 3.3896, 4.2891])
a=gev.fit(t)
```

Based on my linear regression I expected a shape parameter close to c=0, a location parameter close to 3.15 and a scale parameter close to 0.39. The actual result was:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py:1776: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
np.sign(c)*(-g3+(g2+2*g2mg12)*g1)/((g2mg12)**(3./2.)))
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py:1781: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
(g4+(-4*g3+3*(g2+g2mg12)*g1)*g1)/((g2mg12)**2))
```

However, a value is apparently assigned to a, since:

```
>>> a
(0.16458924337692377, 3.1800328240261857, 0.37894174199431357)
```

These values are close to what I expected, but I don't understand the warning.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your code has some calculations in which it is trying to divide by zero or NaN.
You can either fix that by diving into the individual calculations and handling the zeroes and NaNs such that your algorithm skips them or you could do the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import genextreme as gev
with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
    t=np.array([3.8482, 3.6435, 3.0417, 4.0329, 3.2967, 3.3535, 3.6179, 3.3042, 3.6164, 3.5855, 2.7932, 2.8833, 2.6513, 2.7794, 3.2649, 3.2613, 3.1736, 3.1131, 3.3896, 4.2891])
    a=gev.fit(t)
```

This simply suppresses the warning by telling the algorithm to ignore values that are going to be divided by 0 or NaN as a form of exception handling.
Note: `divide` for division by 0, `invalid` for encountering NaN in numpy mathematical operations.
For more information: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html